# Splitting an array to multiple batches, depending to a feature, to predict future events with the help of a RNN

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, recurrent-neural-network

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UknJX.png)I am trying to evaluate an event log(Process Mining) to predict future processes based on the three key attributes "CaseID", "Activity" and "Timestamp" with the help of a RNN.

So far I can only get the following input shape: (1,6882,3). So one batch, 6882 timesteps and three features.

However, I think that the array should be split on the respective "CaseID"-related sequences.
I have about 2000 unique CaseID and 10 different Activities, therefore my input shape should look like this, i think: (2000,10,1)

Do you have an idea or a similar solution, I'm not getting anywhere.

```
#Importing the data set and split
dataset_train = pd.read_csv('minieventlog.csv')
print(dataset_train.head())


X = dataset_train.iloc[:,:].values
Y = dataset_train.iloc[:,:].values

X_train = X_train.reshape(1,6882,3)
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(1,6882,3)
```

Comment: Please show the code, what you've tried already, and any error messages. Otherwise, difficult-to-impossible to help.

Comment: Hey, i added the code and some pictures.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.